# How to programmatically read permissions on MSMQ queues?

Tags: powershell, permissions, msmq

There are tons of online suggestions for setting MSMQ permissions programmatically using .net System.Messaging.MessageQueue SetPermissions method. But I cannot find any system.messaging property that lets me read the permissions currently configured on existing queues.

I'm trying to write a powershell audit script to take stock of dozens of machines configurations, and its almost entirely useless if I can't get the configured permissions for the queues.

I'm open to suggestions for command line options, didn't find anything mentioned in stackoverflow. Yoel's MSMQ WMI provider doesn't expose the necessary info, and as far as I can tell there is no command line provided with MSMQ that gets you this.

Can't believe this is something no one has addressed. Another enterprise product by Microsoft that's missing a fundamental security feature (verification).

Using powershell for the audit, would prefer built in or .net framework solutions, but getting the info by any means necessary (CLI) if need be.

Answer (score 2):

You may be stuck using [P/Invoke to call MQGetQueueSecurity](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mqrt/MQGetQueueSecurity.html).  IIRC the COM interface doesn't have support for reading queue permissions either.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'd like to avoid dll calls if possible. Also, the code only gets the binary security descriptor, which was also available actually if I reg ex parsed the Queue lqs files via powershell. I guess next question is how to get security principals, permissions etc out of this? 
example: `[Properties] 
Label=private$\testtran 
Type=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
QueueName=\private$\testtran Journal=00 Quota=4294967295 
Security=01000780b0000000cc000000000000001400000002009c00050000000000140004000000010100000000000507000000000024003f000f00010500000000000...`

Comment: I haven't thought this through (so I could be going off half cocked) but I think you'll want to use the [System.Security.AccessControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229742.aspx) namespace to peel apart that Access Control List.  Turn it into a byte array and you should at least be able to create a [RawAcl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.rawacl.aspx) out of it.  It might even be possible to turn the byte array into something more useful.

Comment: Too bad I can't count on all the boxes having windows Vista plus... as of Vista WMI has a security descriptor class that can read binary security descriptor and spits out win32_ACE array which contains almost everything (its not clear if it works for MSMQ SDs, will need to try it). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394577(v=vs.85).aspx#the_role_of_security_descriptors

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and took some of the advice that has been suggested here. I made a small c# project that uses p/invoke to get the user's permissions for a given queue.

Please feel free to use or contribute to it:

https://github.com/jlevitt/MSMQSecurity